# Validating input in EditText after focus changed to next EditText in Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have listview, in which there is view which is consist of EditText (which I reuse in listview as item), Now I want like, when user enters data in first edittext (1st row of listview) and changes focus to next edittext(2nd row of listview),then I want to check if user has enter valid input in first edittext.

Please give me a solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly provide your code and what are you trying to do properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [setOnFocusChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)) to run the input validation when the view loses the focus.